# Placing a filename in a filefield in extjs

Tags: extjs, filefield

In my store I have a field called `CreditName`. In my view I am trying to check if `CreditName` is not null and if it is not enter it into my filefield.  I have added a listener to my filefield that will enter text into the filefield.  What I am having trouble with is getting `CreditName` into the filefield.  I know that it is reading from my store because other fields are appearing properly.

Here is my code for my filefield

```
 xtype: 'filefield',
        buttonText: 'Select A File',
        fieldLabel: 'File',
        name: 'Credit',
        labelWidth: 50,
        msgTarget: 'under',
          return true;
        },
        listeners: {
          render: function (comp) {
            comp.setRawValue(CreditName);
          }
        }
```

Here is the store code

```
fields: [ {
    name: 'PartyId',
    type: 'string'
  }, {
    name: 'CreditName',
    type: 'string',
    critical: true
  }],
  proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'api/parties',
    reader: {
      type: 'json'
    }
  }
```

PartyId shows up fine, here is the code for that, it is in the same view as filefield

```
     {
        xtype: 'displayfield',
        name: 'PartyId',
        fieldLabel: ' Party ID'
      },
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your config of 'filefield', you have to use same name as 'name' property in store. In your case, it should be `name: 'CreditName'`, not `'Credit'`.

**--edit--**

You can get model values in 'render' listener like this:

```
render: function (comp) {
    var model = comp.getModelData(),
        value = model.get('CreditName');
    comp.setRawValue(value);
}
```

Comment: I tried that a while back, the filefield text is still blank.

Comment: If you still have 'render' listener in your code to set value, remove it.

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you want to do. If you want to have initial value, you need to use setRawValue in 'render' listener.

Comment: You just want to get a value of 'CreaditName' inside of a 'render' listener and update the filefield, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  That is what I am having trouble figuring out